# How to create a re-usable plugin using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, plugins, libraries, sisense

I'm working on a `Business Intelligence` tool, `Sisense`. It lacks some of the features like `Date picker` or `Calendar`. Is it possible that I create a `plugin` using `ReactJS` and somehow integrate it to the Sisense. Well, I'll take care of the integration part. Help me create a plugin in react. Or should I go with `Angular` or `jquery` ?

An answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469261/creating-a-angular-js-plugin) question says:

> Being a full fledged framework, i don't think this is a good use of AngularJS. It may not even work. Reactjs may be better suited for this scenario.

Please give me some guidance on How to create a plugin whether it is React or Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following link provides basic information about integration between `ReactJS` and `Sisense.js`.

https://support.sisense.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360014654594-Sisense-js-with-ReactJS